# Pulling images from Windows 10 Lock Screen to a different folder

Tags: file, rust

Windows 10 has an interesting feature where it will display "fun facts" and images on the lock screen. Occasionally, these images are something I would want to use for a background.

These images are stored in `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`.

As I wasn't certain if `_cw5n1h2txyewy` would be constant on the `Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager` folder, I wanted to just search the `%LocalAppData%\Packages` directory for `Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager*`, and pull the first directory that matches that pattern.

Then, in that directory, I wanted to copy the images and read a "magic number" from each image, which can vary but determines the image type. In this case, I use the first 4 bytes as `0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47` (or `0x89` then `PNG`), or bytes 6 through 9 as `0x4A 0x46 0x49 0x46` (`JFIF`) or `0x45 0x78 0x69 0x66` (`Exif`). The first condition would add the `png` extension, the second would add `jpg`.

The first function is my `detect_file_type`, which evaluates the file contents and determines what image type it is:

```
fn detect_file_type(data : &Vec<u8>) -> Option<String> {
    if data[0] == 0x89 && data[1] == 0x50 && data[2] == 0x4E && data[3] == 0x47 { // ?PNG
        Some("png".to_string())
    } else if data[6] == 0x4A && data[7] == 0x46 && data[8] == 0x49 && data[9] == 0x46 { // JFIF
        Some("jpg".to_string())
    } else if data[6] == 0x45 && data[7] == 0x78 && data[8] == 0x69 && data[9] == 0x66 { // Exif
        Some("jpg".to_string())
    } else { 
        None
    }
}
```

This is rather simple.

Next, I wanted my directory search function:

```
fn find_dir(search : &str, path : PathBuf) -> Option<PathBuf> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir(path).unwrap() {
        let path = entry.unwrap().path();
        if path.is_dir() {
            if path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().starts_with(search) {
                return Some(path);
            }
        }
    }
    return None;
}
```

Again, rather simple. We stuck to `Option` with both of these so that we can handle the error cases (if we need to).

And finally, we have all the critical work:

```
fn main() {
    let args = 
        App::new("Pull Windows Lock-Screen Pictures")
            .version("0.1")
            .about("Loads the images used for the main Windows 10 Lock-Screen backgrounds to the specified folder (or './out' if not specified).")
            .arg(Arg::with_name("destination")
                .help("The destination directory ('./out' by default)")
                .takes_value(true)
                .required(false))
            .get_matches();

    let my_dirs = Directories::with_prefix("windows_lock_screen_pictures", "Windows_Lock_Screen_Pictures").unwrap();
    let home = my_dirs.bin_home().parent().unwrap().parent().unwrap().join("Packages");
    let dir = find_dir("Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager", home).unwrap().join("LocalState").join("Assets");

    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir).unwrap() {
        let path = entry.unwrap().path();
        if !path.is_dir() {
            let data = fs::read(&path).unwrap();
            let path_str = path.display().to_string();
            let file = path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string();

            let path_ext =
                match detect_file_type(&data) {
                    Some(path_ext) => {
                        let mut res = ".".to_string();
                        res.push_str(&path_ext);
                        res
                    },
                    _ => "".to_string()
                };

            let mut base_dest_dir = "".to_string();
            let mut default = std::env::current_dir().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string();
            default.push_str("\\out\\");
            let dest_dir = args.value_of("destination").unwrap_or(&default);
            base_dest_dir.push_str(dest_dir);

            if !Path::new(&base_dest_dir).exists() {
                fs::create_dir(Path::new(&base_dest_dir)).expect("Could not create directory");
            }

            base_dest_dir.push_str(&file);
            base_dest_dir.push_str(&path_ext);

            println!("{} -> {}", path_str, base_dest_dir);
            fs::write(Path::new(&base_dest_dir), data).expect("Could not write file");
        }
    }
}
```

Overall, we kept things rather small, but still allowed flexibility (and most of the safety we needed).

Our whole program is as follows:

extern crate clap;
    extern crate dirs;

```
use std::fs::{self};
use std::path::{Path,PathBuf};
use clap::{App,Arg};
use dirs::{Directories};

fn detect_file_type(data : &Vec<u8>) -> Option<String> {
    if data[0] == 0x89 && data[1] == 0x50 && data[2] == 0x4E && data[3] == 0x47 { // ?PNG
        Some("png".to_string())
    } else if data[6] == 0x4A && data[7] == 0x46 && data[8] == 0x49 && data[9] == 0x46 { // JFIF
        Some("jpg".to_string())
    } else if data[6] == 0x45 && data[7] == 0x78 && data[8] == 0x69 && data[9] == 0x66 { // Exif
        Some("jpg".to_string())
    } else { 
        None
    }
}

fn find_dir(search : &str, path : PathBuf) -> Option<PathBuf> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir(path).unwrap() {
        let path = entry.unwrap().path();
        if path.is_dir() {
            if path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().starts_with(search) {
                return Some(path);
            }
        }
    }
    return None;
}

fn main() {
    let args = 
        App::new("Pull Windows Lock-Screen Pictures")
            .version("0.1")
            .about("Loads the images used for the main Windows 10 Lock-Screen backgrounds to the specified folder (or './out' if not specified).")
            .arg(Arg::with_name("destination")
                .help("The destination directory ('./out' by default)")
                .takes_value(true)
                .required(false))
            .get_matches();

    let my_dirs = Directories::with_prefix("windows_lock_screen_pictures", "Windows_Lock_Screen_Pictures").unwrap();
    let home = my_dirs.bin_home().parent().unwrap().parent().unwrap().join("Packages");
    let dir = find_dir("Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager", home).unwrap().join("LocalState").join("Assets");

    for entry in fs::read_dir(dir).unwrap() {
        let path = entry.unwrap().path();
        if !path.is_dir() {
            let data = fs::read(&path).unwrap();
            let path_str = path.display().to_string();
            let file = path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string();

            let path_ext =
                match detect_file_type(&data) {
                    Some(path_ext) => {
                        let mut res = ".".to_string();
                        res.push_str(&path_ext);
                        res
                    },
                    _ => "".to_string()
                };

            let mut base_dest_dir = "".to_string();
            let mut default = std::env::current_dir().unwrap().to_str().unwrap().to_string();
            default.push_str("\\out\\");
            let dest_dir = args.value_of("destination").unwrap_or(&default);
            base_dest_dir.push_str(dest_dir);

            if !Path::new(&base_dest_dir).exists() {
                fs::create_dir(Path::new(&base_dest_dir)).expect("Could not create directory");
            }

            base_dest_dir.push_str(&file);
            base_dest_dir.push_str(&path_ext);

            println!("{} -> {}", path_str, base_dest_dir);
            fs::write(Path::new(&base_dest_dir), data).expect("Could not write file");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of general notes.

- The app directory *should* be consistent. It’s a UWP app and this is part of the app package family name. Your implementation is fine though.
- I would take advantage of some strong type instead of `”jpg”` and `”png”` strings.
- Speaking of file type detection, you might want to [use a library like tree_magic](https://docs.rs/tree_magic/0.2.1/tree_magic/)
- You really shouldn’t `unwrap()` unless you’re absolutely sure it shouldn’t fail. It’s really user unfriendly and should be reserved for developer errors. Most of your `unwraps` could fail due to file permissions. In a small app like this, I’d probably go with [expect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) to give a friendlier error message. In something larger, the linked doc contains all the methods you’d expect on a result type.

Some things I like:

- You quickly embraced idioms, like pattern matching and omitting the `return` keyword.

Confusion:

We’ve been reviewing each other’s code for a long time. I’m consistently surprised by your propensity to in-line dense logic in preference to extracting methods. 
I don’t mind the dense logic, I just think you have a general opportunity to *name* things and raise the level of abstraction. For this app, I expect the code to read like this, hiding away the lower level details.

```
let outdir = parse_args().or_else(“./out”);
let files = get_files();
copy_files(files, outdir);
```

Comment: The `expect` didn't even dawn on me and I used it in two places there already...lol